# How to select any element (inputs, selects, textareas) with an specific name with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have various inputs, selects and textareas in a form. I'd like to select one of them based on name without knowing the type of the element with jQuery. I know I can do something like

```
$("input[name=foo], textarea[name=foo], select[name=foo]")
```

but I wonder if I can do it in a more concise way. What do you say?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

`:input[name=foo]`

Comment: Worked flawlessly! I just needed to avoid button and submit inputs, and buttons, so I used $(":input[name=foo]").not(":submit :button"), but it is a minor detail. Again, thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) filter selector:

```
$(':input[name="name here"]')
```

> Description: Selects all input,
>   textarea, select and button elements.
>
> The :input selector basically selects
>   all form controls.

**More Info:** http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/